# Find string matching position?

Tags: java, string, char, string-matching

I have a String like this: `PQqRrp`. Upper case letter followed by lower case letter.

If Upper is followed by its own lower case letter, then there is a match. So I need to go till the point where there is a last match of upper and its lower letter. If lower is matching with its own lower then that's not a match.

Now I need to find the last position at which my character was matching (upper with its lower alphabet). In above case at 5th place, `r was matching with R`.

```
private int getStringMatchNumber(String input) {
    char[] str = input.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    // now I am confuse
}
```

How should I proceed here?

Comment: You would loop, starting from the end, and look for the match. Use `for`, `if` and the appropriate method of java.lang.Character. Read its javadoc to find out the appropriate method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start from end of string and go backwards, in pseudo code:

```
char[] str = input.toCharArray()
for i = str.length-1 down to 1:
   if str[i] is lowercase:
      if toLowerCase(str[i-1]) == str[i] and str[i-1] is uppercase:
         return i-1

return -1  // means no match is found
```

Java code:

```
    char[] str = input.toCharArray();

    for(int i=str.length-1; i>=1; --i) {
        char c = str[i];
        char p = str[i-1];
        if (c == Character.toLowerCase(c) && p == Character.toUpperCase(p)){
            if (Character.toLowerCase(p) == c)
                return i-1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
```

Comment: `toLowerCase` and `toUpperCase` methods don't accept 0 arguments as documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toLowerCase(char))  I suggest you pass the values `c` and `p` appropriately and even access them in a `static` way i.e. in the form `Character.toLowerCase`

Answer (score 1):

The other answers (including the accepted one) don't account for outer matches (e.g. A a in ABba - which should return 3, but the other solutions return 2 as it can't match A with a)

Here is a rough comprehensive solution:

```
private static int getStringMatchNumber(String input) {
    char[] str = input.toCharArray();

    int last = findMatches(str, 0);
    System.out.println("Last unmatched index: " + (last - 1));

    for(int i = str.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
        Character c = str[i];
        Character p = str[i-1];
        if (Character.isLowerCase(c) && Character.isUpperCase(p)){
            if (p == Character.toUpperCase(c))
                return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

private static int findMatches(char[] str, int pos) {

    if(pos+1 >= str.length) {
        return pos;
    }
    Character c = str[pos];
    Character p = str[pos+1];
    int nextPos = 0;

    System.out.println(c + " " + p);

    if (Character.isUpperCase(c) && Character.isLowerCase(p)){
         if (c == Character.toUpperCase(p)) {
             System.out.println("Match found");
             pos = pos+2;
             pos = findMatches(str, pos);
         } else {
             System.out.println("Next lower case letter doesn't match. Stop.");
         }
    } else if(Character.isUpperCase(c) && Character.isUpperCase(p)) {
        System.out.println("Trying to find inner Matches first");

        nextPos = findMatches(str, pos+1);
        if(nextPos < str.length) {
            p = str[nextPos];
            System.out.println("Outer match character: " + p);
            System.out.println(c + " " + p);

            if ((Character.isUpperCase(c) && Character.isLowerCase(p)) && (c == Character.toUpperCase(p))){
                System.out.println("Outer Match found");
                pos = nextPos + 1;
            } else {
                pos = nextPos;
            }
        }
        if(pos < str.length) {
            pos = findMatches(str, pos);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Lower case letter found, will return and find outer match");
    }

    return pos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should proceed by writing the pseudo code of the program.
And from the code you have posted, To what I understand you don't need to convert the input to lower case. That would change everything to lower case and you can't use those values.

I would run a `for` loop from the end of the character array and check each consecutive pair of values if they are equal or not. Since the loop runs from the end, first instance of a match will return the value `i`. The backwards approach is efficient as you are looking for the last match. The method also only uses one if-conditional so will take less memory in the long run.

```
private static int getStringMatchNumber(String input) {
    char[] str = input.toCharArray();
    for(int i = str.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
        Character c = str[i];
        Character p = str[i-1];
        if (Character.isLowerCase(c) && Character.isUpperCase(p)){
            if (p == Character.toUpperCase(c))
                return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please note that if the function returns 0, it means no matching pairs were found. You can check this after the callee.

**EDIT** I have implemented a check for lowercase and uppercase in the matching items (as suggested by others). Do note, that the returned value is the `zero-based` value of the position of lower-cased character in the match. For input value `"aaaBbaa"` the returned value is `4` i.e. the position of `b` in the `Bb` match. You may tweak the algorithm to return the position of `B` by returning `i-1` instead of `i`. In that case you would need to return `-1` instead of `0` to avoid false negatives.

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Comment: There might be some typo errors here and there as I typed it directly into the SE editor. Will update, wait

Comment: @ParasDPain the question is about Java, not C#. But the OP should be able to figure out the translation. Just warn him that this is not compilable code.

Comment: There is very little chance that an uppercase value is equal to a lowercase value. val1 should be str[i], left unmodified. And you should start from the end instead of starting from the beginning, and stop the loop as soon as you found a match.

Comment: Wrong output on "RruyGAhDsAj"

Comment: Thank you @JBNizet and MJafar Mash for the feedback, I have modified the code accordingly. It starts at the end now and returns as soon as a match is found. Also should not give wrong output now.

Comment: It's still wrong. You're still uppercasing one char and lowercasing the other.

Comment: I reckon I fixed that, only changed the last value to be Uppercase. Guess forgot to paste. Fixed

Comment: Then can you suggest a fix please :(

Comment: It's wrong because the actual answer is "0" but you return zero in case of finding no match, so 0 is ambiguous, my answer is a correct implementation.

Comment: It's also wrong on "aaaBBaa", you don't check for `lower` to be lower-case.

Comment: Also wrong on "aaaBbaa", you return position of `b`, but the question asked for posision of `B`, you should return `i-1` in 6th line

Comment: Have you tested your code? There is no way that your program would "survive" the first iteration. It will abort with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on this line `char lower = Character.toUpperCase(str[i]);`.

Comment: Have not tested it but my answer only suggests an implementation, not a full-fedged solutipon and thanks @MJafarMash will implement it

Comment: Regarding returning 0. The user wants to return the value of the lower cased letter (the second value in the match). So 0 will only be returned if there were no match, if the match was the first element, the return will be 1. Please read the question carefully

Comment: The check for lowercase and uppercase is crucial, thanks for that